# Latency in bluetooth headphones?

Tags: headphones, latency

I am thinking of buying some bluetooth headphones because the cabled ones I have make guitar playing difficult while wearing them (the cable touches the neck of the guitar and generally it doesn't give me much freedom to sit as I want).

Will latency be an issue? I already have small latency due to VST instruments and virtual amplification which is bearable but I don't want to add any more latency.

Comment: https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/mdr-zx330bt I am thinking of buying these.

Comment: Why not do what people have been doing for 50 years or more… run the cable down your back or even down the inside of your shirt?

Comment: inside the shirt is a very nice idea I have not thought of to be honest! I doubt if the cable is long enough to do so though. I will try it anyway

Comment: I'm sure an extension cable would be cheaper & more reliable than a BT headset ;) Honestly, I played guitar in recording studios way back when & never once thought to my self, "Ooh, wouldn't it be nice if these were wireless?" The concept simply didn't exist & wouldn't for another 30 years ;)